# spring,jsp,hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsp

I have a `jsp` form which contain nearly 20 input fields.i want to pass the input fields value to the spring controller.My problem is the first five input field is for `Table1` and next for `Table2` etc all are join tables.My question is that how can i get these value in single object using  method like `@modelattribute` or any other method.

Note:-I'm using `hibernate` with `spring` for mapping.  please provide me some link.

Comment: Google for "spring input table": the 3. item "Spring MVC Multiple Row Form Submit in List collection. Multi row..." 
 http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/ is some example. This is a good point to start. -- If you have future questions, come back and ask but you should read "how-to-ask" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before.

Comment: @Sudharsan Selvaraj it is very difficult to explain that thing here.See for some examples in google

Comment: Mr.PSR--i searched google but they had given example for only one table but i need join table example can u give me some link